# Creating another session with a separate Firefox profile in Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to figure out how to have two Firefox profiles running at once in Protractor on two different windows.  My first train of thought was to create another `webdriver.WebDriver.createSession` but I don't quite understand what to put in the 'executor' parameter. I've followed this example here for the first profile https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile, and I've tried multicapabilities but that doesn't really help, as it runs the spec on both browsers.

Comment: I opened an issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1594. I think it is what you want. Please comment on this issue and use it to track updates.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264146/setting-firefox-profile-in-a-setup-with-multiple-browsers/27431562#27431562