# Configuring multiple capabilities with promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, selenium, protractor

This is a follow-up to the [Set firefox profile with protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873378/set-firefox-profile-with-protractor) topic.

According to the [`setFirefoxProfile`](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile) howto, it is possible to set a firefox profile with a special ["helper" js code](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/blob/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile/helper.js) which uses [`firefox-profile`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/firefox-profile) and [`q`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/q) libraries to make an encoded firefox profile on the fly.

This worked for me until I've tried to *use multiple browsers and configuring [`multiCapabilities`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#testing-against-multiple-browsers)*:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            specs: [
                'footer.disabledCookies.spec.js'
            ],
            chromeOptions: {
                prefs: {
                    'profile.default_content_settings.cookies': 2
                }
            }
        },

        ...
        // other capabilities here
        ...

        helper.getFirefoxProfile()    
     },

     ...
}
```

With this setup I'm getting an error (full traceback [here](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/db7d1d8f03cb66224998)):

> Spec patterns did not match any files.

As I understand, this means that the setup with firefox profile is missing `specs` key. In other words, it cannot find any tests to run.

I've tried to [include `specs` into the `capabilities` dictionary inside the helper itself](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/5d6763c1e55a8a4c5747), but the error persists.

How to fix the error and set firefox profile if using `multiCapabilities`?

---

<sup>As a workaround, I've created a separate protractor configuration file with only firefox configured (using `capabilities`) and set `grunt` to run protractor twice - one for this "firefox with a profile" config and the other one for all other browsers.</sup>

Comment: I opened an issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1594. I think it is what you want. Please comment on this issue and use it to track updates.

Comment: @hankduan thank you very much for elaborating this to a feature request. Please make an answer (with some technical details you've provided in the github issue) and I'll accept it. In case the feature would be implemented, we'll update the answer with appropriate instructions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now, protractor can only accept promise as capabilities if we are NOT using multicapabilities. The reason for this is because multiCapabilities runs each task in a new process, so the promise (function) cannot be passed (single capabilities work because we're not forking).

Alternatively we could resolve capabilities in the launcher, before passing the resolved capabilities into the new processes; however, this will break the ability to set up proxies (https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1040), which relies on capability promises to be resolved after driverProvider setup.

I can't think of an easy way of doing this (without large refactoring), but it is definitely doable. 
I created an issue for Protractor (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1594). Please follow that and/or comment on it if this is something you need or you have other ideas to implement it.

For now you would need to use the workaround you mentioned in your original question.

**UPDATE**

https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1629 supports this. Starting in protractor 1.6 (or if you sync to master) you can pass in a function to `config.getMultiCapabilities` like `onPrepare` and `onCleanup`. This function can return a promise to `multiCapabilties` (i.e. array of `capabilities`).

See https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/getCapabilitiesConf.js for an example.

Comment: That's amazing, tried that - it is working! (I've added an answer with an example of how have I configured protractor using `getMultiCapabilities()`) Going to award you with an additional bounty. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Following the [pull request](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1629) sent by @hankduan, here is how have I used [`getMultiCapabilities()`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/getCapabilitiesConf.js) to combine different capabilities where one of them is a promise (needed for `firefox-profile` to be set):

```
"use strict";

var FirefoxProfile = require("firefox-profile");
var q = require("q");

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",

    getMultiCapabilities: function() {
        var deferred = q.defer();

        var multiCapabilities = [
            {
                browserName: "chrome",
                specs: [
                    "footer.disabledCookies.spec.js"
                ],
                chromeOptions: {
                    prefs: {
                        "profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                browserName: "chrome",
                specs: [
                    "*.spec.js"
                ],
                exclude: [
                    "footer.disabledCookies.spec.js",
                    "footer.disabledJavascript.spec.js",
                    "footer.disabledFlash.spec.js"
                ]
            },
            {
                browserName: "chrome",
                specs: [
                    "footer.disabledFlash.spec.js"
                ],
                chromeOptions: {
                    args: [
                        "--disable-internal-flash",
                        "--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash",
                        "--disable-plugins-discovery"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ];

        // Wait for a server to be ready or get capabilities asynchronously.
        setTimeout(function() {
            var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
            firefoxProfile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", false);
            firefoxProfile.encoded(function (encodedProfile) {
                var capabilities = {
                    "browserName": "firefox",
                    "firefox_profile": encodedProfile,
                    "specs": [
                        "footer.disabledJavascript.spec.js"
                    ]
                };
                multiCapabilities.push(capabilities);
                deferred.resolve(multiCapabilities);
            });
        }, 1000);

        return deferred.promise;
    },

    ...

};
```

Hope this would help somebody in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the example. (One thing: you don't need the setTimeout)

Comment: @hankduan not sure why, but without `setTimeout()` protractor is exiting with error code 100 (no failing tests though). Here is a [complete traceback](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/446f15c78434665766db). With `setTimeout()` no errors, working.