# Multiple browsers in sequence with multicapabilities

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Currently, I am using different Firefox profiles setup with multi-capabilities with some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619251/multiple-firefox-profiles-in-protractor). Each of my Firefox profiles is set up with a client certificate which differentiates it from others.

Is there a way create a test where the different profiles can interact with each other?

I know that you can spawn new browsers in sequence in a test using [browser.forkNewDriverInstance](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#using-multiple-browsers-in-the-same-test). 
I want to combine this with the browsers I set up in multi-capabilities to run tests in sequence using custom Firefox profiles and not in parallel.

So my protractor.conf.js would look like this:

```
...
getMultiCapabilities: function () {
    return q.all([
        newFirefoxProfile('test/firefox-profile-1'),
        newFirefoxProfile('test/firefox-profile-2')
    ]);
},
...
```

And in a test.spec.js file:

```
describe('my account', function () {

    var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance();
    //rather than fork new instance, I want a different capability instance

    it('should have grant new authority', function () {
        //browser 1 gives new authority to browser 2
        //browser2.get('#/my-account/details');
        //browser2 verify new authority
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to list your browsers in `multiCapabilities`

Just look at the accepted answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239768/e2e-testing-on-multiple-parallel-browsers-in-protractor)

Hope this helps. :)